# Sublime: Good plugin for git history

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

In Atom Editor, there is a plugin that lets you view the commit history of a single file. Does sublime have a similar plugin?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out GitSavvy - it's a new package for Sublime Text - https://github.com/divmain/GitSavvy

Comment: I couldn't figure this out. Then asked a question but it takes days to get a response.

Answer (score 3):

I am using [GitGutter](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter), it has a nice set of features

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try the popular, [SublimeGit](https://sublimegit.net/), which has integration in both Sublime Text 2 and 3 (though it costs money after the free trail).

Or [GitCommitMsg](https://github.com/cbumgard/GitCommitMsg), which:

> Shows the git commit history for one or more lines of code.
>   Essentially it performs a git blame on the selected line(s) of code,
>   and then performs a git show on the resulting commit(s).